# Detecting multiple instances of word with .contains

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to count the number of instances a certain string occurs within another string. The input string that I am searching is not formatted in any fashion.

I am currently doing the below but it is obvious that it only counts .contains once. What is the most efficient way to count instances multiple times.

```
 public String computeBestFitKey() {
    if(this.inputText == null)
        return null;
    String answer = null;
    int bestCount = 0, tempCount = 0;
    for(String s: logicTemplate.getLogicMap().keySet()) {
        String[] keyWords = this.logicTemplate.getKeyWords(s);
        for(String word: keyWords) {
            if(this.inputText.toLowerCase().contains(word.toLowerCase())) {
                System.out.println("word found: "+word.toLowerCase());
                tempCount++;
            }
        }
        if(tempCount > bestCount) {
            bestCount = tempCount;
            answer = s;

        }
        tempCount = 0;
    }
    return answer;
}
```

Comment: Use `indexOf` method with `fromIndex`

Comment: Can you give some input/output examples?

Comment: How many times `HoHo` exists in `HoHoHo`? Once or twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using [`indexOf(string str, int startFrom)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int,%20int)).

Replace this line: `if(this.inputText.toLowerCase().contains(word.toLowerCase())) {`

With these:

```
int lastIndex = -1;
String lowerTextInput = this.inputText.toLowerCase();
String lowerWord = word.toLowerCase();
while((lastIndex = (lowerTextInput .indexOf(lowerWord , lastIndex + 1)) > 0)
```

What this does is that it assigns `lastIndex` the value of your substring. If the string does not contain the substring, it will yield -1 and thus the `while` condition will break. If it does exist, the value of `lastIndex` will be incremented by 1 and the search is made again.

If you would like to make some improvements to this, especially if you are searching large strings, then I recommend you increase the value of `lastIndex` by the length of the substring you have matched.

Comment: @Pshemo: Yes I agree, did it that way for simplicity. Anyways answer updated.

Answer (score 3):

If you just need to count occurrences of a word, and it's not a homework assignment where you are restricted from using some of the standard facilities, then you can just do

```
int numOccurrences = 0;
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(word, Pattern.LITERAL).matcher(input); 
while (m.find()) numOccurrences++;
```

`Pattern.LITERAL` is used to treat all character literally and ignore its special meaning in regex, if any.

Answer (score 0):

```
static int countOccurences(String haystack, String needle)
{
    int index, lastIndex = -1, count = 0;

    while ((index = haystack.indexOf(needle, lastIndex + 1)) != -1)
    {
        lastIndex = index;
        ++count;
    }

    return count;
}
```

Comment: No need for substring, which could be inefficient. Just use the overload of `indexOf()` that takes a starting index.

Comment: Could you add some explanation?